# Creating Select Fields in a module with Drupal 7

Tags: entities

I am trying to write my own module to add a content type with the help of [node_example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_example!node_example.module/7) and [this page](http://drupaltutorial4u.blogspot.nl/2011/04/drupal-7-field-api-setup-new-content.html). I made small tweaks and got it to work, yet I cannot find any example to create a select box as a field, and I failed in my each attempt. I have also checked the official documentation for [field_create_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_create_field/7), still no clues.

Is there any documentation or sample you can guide me?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
// Create field definition
$field = field_info_field('field_my_select_field');
if (empty($field)) {
  $field = array(
    'active' => '1',
    'cardinality' => '1',
    'deleted' => '0',
    'entity_types' => array(),
    'field_name' => 'field_my_select_field',
    'foreign keys' => array(),
    'indexes' => array(
      'value' => array(
        0 => 'value',
      ),
    ),
    'module' => 'list',
    'settings' => array(
      'allowed_values' => array(
        'Yes' => 'Yes',
        'No' => 'No',
      ),
      'allowed_values_function' => '',
    ),
    'translatable' => '0',
    'type' => 'list_text',
  );

  $field = field_create_field($field);
  drupal_set_message('Created field_my_select_field');
}

// Create field instance on entity bundle
if(!field_info_instance('node', 'field_my_select_field', 'my_node_type')){
  $instance = array(
    'bundle' => 'terms',
    'default_value' => array(
      0 => array(
        'value' => 'Yes',
      ),
    ),
    'deleted' => '0',
    'description' => '',
    'display' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'label' => 'hidden',
        'module' => 'list',
        'settings' => array(),
        'type' => 'hidden',
        'weight' => '4',
      ),
    ),
    'entity_type' => 'node',
    'field_name' => 'field_my_select_field',
    'label' => 'My field label',
    'required' => 0,
    'settings' => array(),
    'widget' => array(
      'active' => 1,
      'module' => 'options',
      'settings' => array(),
      'type' => 'options_select',
      'weight' => '3',
    ),
  );
  field_create_instance($instance);
  drupal_set_message("Added field_my_select_field field to node");
}
```